# Can't cast char number to int with atoi()

Tags: c, casting, atoi

I've been messing with this toy code for a while but I can't figure out why it wont cast the char number to an int.  Can someone explain this to me?

Thanks,

```
#include <stdio.h> 

void fun(char a[]);



int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
char b[] = {'2','8'};

fun(b);

}

void fun(char a[]){


int i = 2 * atoi(a[0]);
int j = 2 * atoi(a[1]);
printf("this is i: %d, this is j: %d\n", i, j);
}
```

it returns this error:
new.c: In function ‘fun’:
new.c:25:22: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘atoi’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
int i = 2 * atoi(a[0]);

Comment: Atoi expects the character array (ie the string) to be null terminated

Comment: I tried it with b[] = {'2', '8', '\0'}; but had the same issue

Comment: I'd expect `atoi(a[0])` to warn.  `atoi()` expects a pointer to a _string_, not a `char`.  Rice Man, What compiler and warnings are you using?

Comment: gcc new.c -o run
new.c: In function ‘fun’:
new.c:25:22: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘atoi’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     int i = 2 * atoi(a[0]);
                      ^

Comment: In file included from new.c:3:0:
/usr/include/stdlib.h:81:5: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘char’
 int atoi (const char *__nptr);
     ^~~~
new.c:26:22: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘atoi’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     int j = 2 * atoi(a[1]);
                      ^
In file included from new.c:3:0:
/usr/include/stdlib.h:81:5: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘char’
 int atoi (const char *__nptr);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better representation of what's actually happening in char *argv[]
and a fully functional code!

```
#include <stdio.h> 

void fun(char *a[]);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
// assume command line input was:
// ./a.out 10 11
printf("argc: %d\n", argc);
printf("argv[0]: %s\n", argv[0]);
printf("argv[1]: %s\n", argv[1]);
printf("argv[2]: %s\n", argv[2]);
printf("argv[argc]: %s\n", argv[argc]);
printf("\n");

char c[] = {"10\0"};
char d[] = {"4\0"};
char e[] = {"7\0"};
char n[] = {'\0'};
char *a[] = {c, d, e, n};

fun(a);

}

void fun(char *a[]){
int j = 0;

while(*a[j] != '\0'){
    printf("atoi(a[%d]): %d\n", j, atoi(a[j]));
    j++;
}// end of while
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you need to convert `2` and `8` characters separately to a number. You need two different arrays to convert the numbers

```
char a[] = "2";
char b[] = "8";

i = atoi (a);
j = atoi (b);
```

If you only want to convert single digit numbers an easier way using characters instead of strings is as below

```
char a = '2';
char b = '8';

i = '2' - '0';
j = '2' - '0';
```

Comment: Thanks; a couple of years ago I was writing a c program and I was testing my function.  The program was supposed to take in command line parameters or get user input.  I wrote this program as a simulation before adding it to my code.  The char array b[] represents the user input of three single digits.  I would then convert each char to an int using atoi() and run another function, but of course it never worked and I never learned why or how to fix it.  So, now it's time :)

Comment: Ok, it's been a long time in the making, but I think I finally figured out what went wrong with this program.  My understanding of the "execution environment" i.e "command line parameters" was incorrect.  I thought the main() argument, *argv[], was holding an array of chars i.e. char x[] = {'1', '2', '3'}; however, it's clearly an array of char pointers.  I think I've just seen it so often and typed so much that I never noticed that that is what it is.  Here is an updated version of the code that more accurately represents what it looks like:

Comment: Here are two links that offer a much better technical explanation of what's really going on in the main() function: 1) https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function (2) https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok

Comment: Originally, I had been using atoi() to convert argv[x] parameters to ints assuming that the argv[x]'s were single chars, which they are not.  This explains why my first program never worked right, because I was giving atoi() single chars, erroneously thinking this was mimicking command line input; as was mentioned earlier, atoi() expects a string and only works with them.